# WooCommerce Subscription With Changing Products Each Week

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a food subscription company where people can purchase 5 meals for the week, and each week their PayPal is debited. **But every week the menu changes.**

So I can accept a payment for a subscription, and within that product I have addons that are different meals, so:

Product: 5 meals subscription
Addon: Chicken Meal x3
Add: Fish Meal x2

The problem is, the next week I don't want to offer Chicken and Fish, I want to offer Beef and Pork.

So how do I allow my clients to go in and select which meals they want from the new weekly menu?

Is there a software that allows you to edit the addons for a subscription product?

Currently I'm running WooCommerce with Woocommerce Custom Product Addons (5.x.x) paid.

Any help would be awesome.